# Extracting data out of Complex JSON

Tags: python, json, ros

[This is the JSON data I am using](https://github.com/hofbi/telecarla/blob/master/telecarla_manual_control/config/multi_sensors.json)

In this dataset, I want to extract the value of "yaw" and store it into in camera_loc. My first attempt for the code was as follows:

```
with open(
        "/home/siddhant/catkin_ws/src/view-adaptation/multi_sensors.json"
    ) as sensors:
        multi_sensors = json.load(sensors)
    camera_loc = [
        multi_sensors["sensors"][0]["yaw"],
        multi_sensors["sensors"][1]["yaw"],
        multi_sensors["sensors"][2]["yaw"],
        multi_sensors["sensors"][3]["yaw"],
        multi_sensors["sensors"][4]["yaw"],
        multi_sensors["sensors"][5]["yaw"],
    ]
```

This gives me the expected result.
But I want to generalize the same for any number of entries in the 'sensors' array.
I tried executing a 'for' loop and extracting the values for the same as follows:

```
for i in multi_sensors["sensors"]:
            camera_loc = []
            camera_loc.append(i["yaw"])
```

However, this method only gives a single value in the camera_loc list which is the last 'yaw' value from the JSON file. I am looking for a better approach or even any modifications to the way I execute the loop so that I can extract all the values of 'yaw' from the JSON file - in this example there are 6 entries but I want to generalize it for 'n' entries that may be created in other cases.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're defining your `camera_loc` array inside the loop, meaning every iteration resets it to `[]`. This code should work if you remove the array definition from the loop:

```py
camera_loc = []
for i in multi_sensors["sensors"]:
    camera_loc.append(i["yaw"])
```

This is also a perfect use case for a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
camera_loc = [i["yaw"] for i in multi_sensors["sensors"]]
```

Both answers results in the same array though, so you may choose whichever you like most.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The suggestion worked. I had used this format in one of my attempts but turns out I had made some basic mistake in syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it happens. Whenever that kind of stuff happens, you can always put a `print` at the end of each iteration to see the contents of the array after all operations are done.

Comment: Thanks again! Have to use this in ROS, hence the absence of 'print' but I'll ensure I use a print and comment it out towards  the end henceforth!

Comment: I didn't meant to leave the print there forever lol, just use it whenever things are strange to see what's happening with your data, and remove it when you solve the issues.